# Script to add group/user to "log on as a service"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to create a script that add a certain user/group to "log on as a service" in my Windows 2008 box. However I have tried using the ntrights.exe, downloaded it and ran the line `ntrights +r SeInteractiveLogonRight -u CSSGroup` in cmd but it failed because of the incompatibility.

Can someone help me or point me in any other useful direction?

Comment: Mostly an aside: Why could you not use group policy for this?

Comment: From my understanding I cant use group policy because it will overwrite the settings from other applications within this machine. And i also have to add this to other specific machines so the only way I was advised was this approach i am taking. Not sure if this answers the question

Comment: What does "it failed because of the incompatibility" mean? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

These things are stored in the registry. Only System has access. So use psexec

```
psexec -s -i <your script>
```

to run script as system giving you access to the security info (which you'll have to turn on and compare to regkeys when turned off as they are in binary structures).

You can also take ownership of the keys and give yourself permission to access.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an open-source replacement (and, I think, improvement) on the `ntrights` utility:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan

The replacement command for the use case in the original question would be:

```
privman -a CSSGroup -g SeInteractiveLogonRight
```

This command would grant the `CSSGroup` group the "Allow log on locally" user right.